# how to include all headers in mail string

Tags: php, string, forms, header

I have 3 fields in my feed back form. These fields are mentioned in the php code also. the email is sent fine but with one problem. only one field that i mention in mail string of $name is being sent to email. if i include $comments field then it is not working. please help. the php code is as follows:

```
<?php
 /*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "cmqaiser.ihrc@gmail.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "contact.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$name = $_REQUEST['full_name'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
$injections = array('(\n+)',
'(\r+)',
'(\t+)',
'(%0A+)',
'(%0D+)',
'(%08+)',
'(%09+)'
);
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments) || empty($name)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
$name, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: please help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `mail()` you should include the variable within the quotation marks if text is including with it, also `header` should come first, otherwise it's meaningless.

```
header ( "Location: $thankyou_page" );

  mail ( $webmaster_email, 
         "Feedback Form Results: $name\n",
         $comments,
         "From: $email_address\n");
```

Comment: If i add another field besides $comments. How will i dot it.  i have tried adding but the data is not being sent. its empty.